# AMPscript to update a Contact Record in Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a backbone of code where I am passing the subscriber key to a landing page from an email. I want that when a subscriber clicks and is redirected to the page to update 2 records in Salesforce.

I am able to pass the info of Subscriber Key in the URL & I am able to do the `RetrieveSalesforceObjects` but not the `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject`. I don't know what I am missing.

Below is the code from my page & info populated when redirect link from email is clicked:

```
%%[ var @SubscriberKey, @SalesforceID,@AccountIsFound, @ContactIsFound, @Proceed, @Certification,@Known, @updateRecord, @valueCert, @valueKnown

     /* Get parameters passed through the URL */

    SET @SubscriberKey = QueryParameter("SubscriberKey")
    SET @SalesforceID = Substring(@SubscriberKey, 0, 15)
    SET @AccountIsFound = "False"
    SET @ContactIsFound = "False"
    SET @Proceed = "True"


    /* Get Account information using the contact ID */

    SET @AccountRowset = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Account", "Id, PersonEmail, PersonContactId, Certification__pc, Known_As__pc",
              "PersonContactId", "=", @SalesforceID)
     /* If it finds an account, get data from it */
    IF RowCount(@AccountRowset) > 0 THEN
                SET @AccountIsFound = "True"
                SET @AccountRow = Row(@AccountRowset,1)
                SET @AccountID = FIELD(@AccountRow, "Id")
        SET @Email = FIELD(@AccountRow, "PersonEmail")
                SET @Certification=FIELD(@AccountRow,"Certification__pc")
                SET @Known=FIELD(@AccountRow,"Known_As__pc")

    ELSE
      SET @Proceed = "False"
      InsertDE("Preference Centre Error Log", "SubscriberKey", @SubscriberKey,
                                                "Custom Message", "Account Not Found",
                                                "Status Message", "ERROR",
                                                "Error Date", NOW())
    ENDIF
SET @valueCert='BOZI'
SET @valueKnown='GDPR'
set @updateRecord=UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Account",@Id,"Certification__pc",@valueCert,"Known_As__pc",@valueKnown)
]%%
<br>
18 char Contact ID: %%=v(@SubscriberKey)=%%
<br>
15 char Contact ID: %%=v(@SalesforceID)=%%
<br>
%%=v(@AccountRowset)=%%
<br>
Email from Account : %%=v(@Email)=%%
<br>
Certification: %%=v(@Certification)=%%
<br>
Known : %%=v(@Known)=%%
<br>
<html>
%%[if @updateRecord == 1 then]%%
         ﹤p﹥Record Updated﹤/p﹥
      %%[ elseif @updateRecord == 0 then]%%
        ﹤pUpdate Failed﹤/p﹥
%%[endif]%%
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem might be because you are setting the `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` as opposed to calling the function. Try removing the `set @UpdateRecord`

i.e.

```
UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Account",@Id,"Certification__pc",@valueCert,"Known_As__pc",@valueKnown)
```

Comment: Thanks @Data_Kid. I tried to do that but no luck. I changed the code slightly to: SET @valueCert='BOZI'
SET @valueKnown='GDPR'
SET @updated=UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Account",@Id,"Certification__pc",@valueCert,"Known_As__pc",@valueKnown) 
SET @Certification=FIELD(@updated,"Certification__pc")
SET @Known=FIELD(@updated,"Known_As__pc")    
This time I got an error message related to the fact                                                    Error Message: Invalid object property name. Object Type: System.Int32 Property Name: Certification__pc

Comment: I'm not sure about this but some parts of your code use single quotes ('), and some does double quotes ("). Try changing
SET @valueCert='BOZI'
SET @valueKnown='GDPR'
to double quotes